# Appropriate test to use when each sample is a permutation from $S_k$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

Suppose I have a dataset $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ where each $x_i$ is a permutation of $\{1, \ldots, k\}$.
[For example, if $k=4$ the data might be $x_1 = (2, 1, 3, 4)$, $x_2 = (3, 2, 4, 1)$, $x_3 = (4, 3, 1, 2)$, etc.]

Real-life context: each person in a study is shown the same set of $k$ dogs and $k$ owners, and is asked to guess which dog belongs to which owner. Their response can be encoded as a permutation. There is also a "correct" pairing of dogs and owners.

I'm wondering how to formalize the following questions.

### 1. Are the results different from random guessing?

- We could do a goodness of fit test with the null being the uniform distribution over all permutations. But it feels like this would require a lot of data since there are $k!$ permutations.
- If we make a contingency table (?) of dogs vs. owners, where the cell $O_{ij}$ counts the number of times a participant paired dog $i$ with a owner $j$, then the null hypothesis would expect each cell to be $E_{ij} = n/k$. Could we do a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Example_chi-squared_test_for_categorical_data) using the statistic $\sum_{i, j} \frac{(O_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}}$ and degrees of freedom $(k-1)^2$? This also feels a little wrong because each study participant contributes $k$ counts to this table (each of which does not share any rows/columns the other), which is different from the usual simple random sample setup for contingency tables (i.e., each participant pairs one dog with one owner).

### 2. Are the participants able to detect the "correct" pairings?

- I am less sure of how to set this up. It feels like the correct pairings could be used as some sort of alternative hypothesis, but I'm not sure how that would help answer the question.
- A notion of "distance" between permutations seems relevant here, since being close to the correct answer should be better than being far. The [Hamming distance](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/11/13/permutation-distance/) seems intuitive for rewarding getting some pairings correct.

Comment: The standard example of this problem is Fisher's ["Lady Tasting Tea"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea) experiment.  The analysis is straightforward and, I believe, extends without any serious modification to your application.

Comment: @whuber Thanks very much for the pointer! Could you take a look at my answer to see I have adapted Fisher's approach appropriately?

Comment: Yes, that looks like the right approach (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question and I agree with your concerns and reasoning. One useful method I can think of is the rank-ordered logit model https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/c7.miscmodels.html. Ranking four alternatives as 3-1-4-2 has a probability P(3-1-4-2) = P(3 in 1,2,3,4) * P(1 in 1,2,4) * P(4 in 2,4) and each P() is `exp(chosen)/sum exp(alternative)`. Ranking among M alternatives is a product of (M-1) conditional probabilities.

This model technique requires a top-to-last rank in terms of utility. If one participant gives a rank among four people based on a fixed sequence of four dogs, then there should be 4 + 3 + 2 = 9 records per participant. If you recorded the timing of each pair submitted separately, we could assume the pair in the earliest submission had the highest utility (e.g., a latent matching score, so a pair with the highest score was easiest to match and submit first) while the latest one had the lowest. In another way to examine the process, let us assume that the rank of dogs for a participant is fixed. For example, the photos of dogs are displayed 1-2-3-4 from left to right, so a participant must find the owner of dog 1 before considering any owner of dog 2. If this sequence of decision making can be determined (a data processing task instead of a modeling result), the rank-ordered logit model can be used. However, we may not tell the first to fourth choices out of four parallel or simultaneous matching. A random shuffling of photos easily overturn such a rank-in-order assumption.

If the four matchings are made simultaneously, cannot be ranked, or are not recorded sequentially, I propose to construct the process as selecting four pairs out of 16 dog-owner pairs. Although in reality selecting each additional pair rules out the possibility of `3 * 2 = 6`, `2 * 2 = 4`, and `1 * 2 = 2` other pairs respectively, the model should consider all 16 possibilities if the selection sequence was not recorded. Because we did not collect sequential ranking information, we cannot eliminate certain possibilities for better precision but will have to consider more scenarios, which increase uncertainty. Specifically, the model predicts the owner of a dog among four candidates, repeated over four dogs for each participant. Therefore, it is a multinomial model of four alternatives per individual with four repeated measurements.

Another debate is how to code the predictors. I recommend four types:

1. specific to a dog, such as length;
2. specific to an owner, such as height;
3. specific to a dog-owner pair, such as similarity in their hair colors;
4. specific to a participant, such as age group.

Some interactions between dog and owner predictors as well as between participant-specific predictors and other predictors might be needed to capture heterogenous effects. If you have many dogs and many owners, we could model unobserved dog and owner effects as random effects, random intercepts grouped by dog and owner and nested within participant specifically. This still works if no predictors are measured but only IDs of the dog, owner, and participant are retained. Random effects, if any, should not be grouped by dog-owner pair if each pair has only one record.

- To test "Are the results different from random guessing?" is to test whether all predictors in the multinomial model (maybe including intercepts although I don't think we need any intercepts, as all dog-owner alternatives are abstract) are simultaneously zero. The repeated-measurement version of chi-square test is McNemar’s chi-square tests for symmetry, which does not seem to meet your task as the categories in a dog-owner (i.e. before-after) square table are arbitrary.
- To examine if the participants can detect the correct pairings, we can (1) construct a dummy variable for whether an alternative is correct and see if its coefficient is zero, which tests whether the correct pairing has any additional effects that existing predictors fail to carry; (2) make predictions and see if the correct alternatives have the highest probabilities or the confidence interval of the probability cross 1/4; (3) tabulate the confusion matrix which collapses predicted probabilities to the highest pair and compare with the correct pair.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you `whuber` for the pointer to ["Lady tasting tea"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea). The key insight [that I failed to consider] is to focus on the statistic of "number of correct pairings," rather than the distribution of all permutations.

Let $T$ be the number of correct pairings from a single participant's response, taking values between $0$ and $k$. Under the null hypothesis (participant pairs dogs with owners randomly), we have
$$P(T=t) = \frac{\#\{\text{permutations with exactly $t$ fixed points}\}}{k!} = \frac{1}{t!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-t} \frac{(-1)^j}{j!},$$
where the last expression can be derived using a formula for the number of derangements (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2465815/43949)).

This distribution seems to have most of its mass near zero (indeed, it's straightforward to show its mean is $1$). One oddity is that the tail is not strictly decreasing, since $P(T=k-1)=0$ (if you have $k-1$ correct pairings, the remaining pairing must also be correct) and $P(T=k)=1/n! > 0$. Regardless, we can use this distribution to set up a hypothesis test.

For $k=6$, the PMF of $T$ is as follows.

| $t$ | $P(T=t)$ |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.368 |
| 1 | 0.367 |
| 2 | 0.188 |
| 3 | 0.056 |
| 4 | 0.021 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0.001 |

So for a single participant, we reject the null hypothesis of "no ability to identify the correct pairings" at the 5% significance level if they get $\ge 4$ correct pairs.

---

The above describes how to test if a single participant's guess is better than random guessing.
If we want to make a statement about a sample of $n$ participants rather than a single participant, we could use $\overline{T}_n = \frac{1}{n}(T_1 + \cdots + T_n)$ (where $T_i$ are i.i.d. from the above distribution) as the statistic and

- compute the exact distribution of $\overline{T}_n$ under the null hypothesis, or
- appeal to the Central Limit Theorem, having computed mean and variance of $T_1$.

Comment: If it helps, this is the [matching distribution](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1740-9713.2018.01167.x).